# Error: spawn EPERM and Error: spawn ENOENT

Tags: node.js, pdf, npm, phantomjs, markdown

I'm trying to convert a markdown to pdf using the npm package **markdown-pdf** with the code below of `index.js` and I'm getting these errors after run `node index.js`.

The first error I got is on my Windows 10 Host Machine, and the second one is on my Ubuntu Guest VirtualBox VM.

Any idea of how to solve this? Anything related with **phantomjs** package?

index.js

```
var markdownpdf = require("markdown-pdf"),
             fs = require("fs")

markdownpdf().from("./README.md").to("./curriculo.pdf", function() {
    console.log("Converted to PDF successfully!")
})
```

Terminal Output Error - Windows Host VM

```
internal/child_process.js:319
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
^

Error: spawn EPERM
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:378:9)
    at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:143:15)
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\User\Documents\localdev\curriculo\node_modules\markdown-pdf\index.js:117:22)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:512:14)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:386:3)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:376:7)
```

Terminal Output Error - Ubuntu Guest VM

```
stream.js:74
    throw er; // Unhandled stream error in penter code hereipe.
^

Error: spawn /media/sf_localdev/curriculo/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

Comment: check system environment variable and add `C:\windows\system32` in system variables `Paths`!

Comment: Yes adding `C:\windows\system32` to the path works

Comment: @MHS may I know how do you know it's was the problem with env. variable? just to learn the debugging process..