# npm install Error: spawn EPERM at ChildProcess.spawn

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have no idea what this error is all about, I have two package.json, I run node.js within another, when I run the outer package.json it shows no error but when I run inner package.json I see the following error

```
node-pty@0.9.0 install C:\agent\_work\1\s\clientsettings\node_modules\node-pty
node scripts/install.js

internal/child_process.js:313
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn EPERM
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:313:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:503:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\agent\_work\1\s\clientsettings\node_modules\node-pty\scripts\install.js:11:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
```

I see the following link is somewhat linked to my question but I do have environment variable set to **C:\windows\system32**                         [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437741/error-spawn-eperm-and-error-spawn-enoent)

Also Note : previously the npm distribution had a problem [Error when I run npm install Error: 404 Not Found: 7zip-bin@~4.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185963/error-when-i-run-npm-install-error-404-not-found-7zip-bin4-1-0)

Comment: Sorry, what? You have _two_ package.json? File names are not duplicable, you can only ever have one file called `package.json` (with that exact all-lowercase filename). That aside, you're not showing any of the code that's involved in generating this error, and there's no indication that you're reduced your code by running through a [mcve] exercise to make sure it's not something obvious but easily overlooked in your own code/config.... can you please do that first, and then update your post?

Comment: sure  Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans

Comment: Also remember to _look at your post_ and fix any markup problems. In this case, if you need to show code, or preformatted text, don't use the syntax for text-quoting =)

Comment: The error is in node-pty, on line 11 in scripts/install.js, which is https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty/blob/master/scripts/install.js#L11, where we see it tries to run node-gyp. Under normal circumstances, that should work but since it doesn't: which version of node and npm are you running? (also, since you can't have two package.json files in the same dir, please add some more details about your file system organisation here)